# Passing new / old parameters in audit tables?

Tags: t-sql, parameters, triggers, sql-server-2012, audit

So as I understand, the audit tables are some kind of tracking tables (ie to capture changes in base table)

How INSERT / UPDATE op works with old and new values? Dunno how to code it

I need to write old and new values of AddressLine1 FROM Person.Address

That's all what I have:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

    -- AL1 is AddressLine1
-- also what about primary key???
CREATE TABLE AuditTable
(
    AL1Old      nvarchar(60)    not null,
    AL1New      nvarchar(60)    not null,
);
GO

-- should I update AuditTable there? 
-- I don't know how to insert Old and New value by trigger...
CREATE TRIGGER triggy
ON Person.Address
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
-- ???
GO
```

Comment: Don't you need a timestamp of something in your audit table? Start thinking about what you need from that audit table and tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert the old and new data in a trigger, then that'll **only** work in an `UPDATE` trigger - the `INSERT` trigger doesn't have any "old" data, obviously.

Basically, you need to get the old data from the `Deleted` pseudo table, and the new data from the `Inserted` pseudo table.

Also: be aware that a trigger is called **once per statement** and both pseudo tables can (and will!) contain multiple rows -so program your trigger accordingly.

To handle the `Addressline1` column - try something like this (and yes, I would also recommend to include the primary key to identify what row this data is for!)

```
-- AL1 is AddressLine1
-- also what about primary key???
CREATE TABLE AuditTable
(
    PrimaryKey INT NOT NULL,
    AL1Old      nvarchar(60)    not null,
    AL1New      nvarchar(60)    not null,
);
GO

-- I don't know how to insert Old and New value by trigger...
CREATE TRIGGER addressUpdateTrigger
ON Person.Address
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.AuditTable(PrimaryKey, AL1Old, AL1New)
       SELECT
          Inserted.AddressID,      -- primary key
          Deleted.AddressLine1,    -- old data
          Inserted.AddressLine1    -- new data
       FROM 
          Inserted
       INNER JOIN
          Deleted on Inserted.AddressID = Deleted.AddressID

GO
```

Comment: Godlike answer, THANKS!